# Black screen after button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm quite new to Objective-C. I want to go to another view controller but it shows me only the black screen after the button click. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)measuring1stscan:(id)sender {
    measuringscan *second = [[measuringscan alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

*measuringscan is the name for another view controller

Comment: Is your view controller based on a nib? If not, don't use the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method. BTW - standard naming conventions dictate that classnames should begin with uppercase letters. Variable and method names should begin with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

viewConreoller default is no color, it is black. just add `second.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

```
 - (IBAction)measuring1stscan:(id)sender {
measuringscan *second = [[measuringscan alloc] init];
second.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: im sorry. im not trying to change colour. :)

Answer (score 0):

@rose is right try to give different color and then check.

Still you face same issue then try to run below code.

Embadded viewcontroller into navigation controller and give unique identifier to second viewcontroller.

```
- (IBAction)measuring1stscan:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"StoryboardWithName"] bundle:NULL];
    measuringscan *second = [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewcontrollerIdentifier"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How do you know the OP has a storyboard?

Comment: And why change the call to `presentViewController:` to `pushViewController`?

Comment: I just assumed that he has passed nib name nil so may be another is storyboard. And he is new so i just suggest another solution.

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions. It would be better to ask questions as comments to the question. Once you have enough details, then post an answer.

Comment: i completely new to this. i try to implement this code, it shows signal SIGABRT. what is that mean?

Comment: @IsmaelBinAzman SIGABRT generally means that the program threw an exception. Could you please provide some information from debugger console?

Comment: 2015-12-02 14:45:32.256 ipad[21788:1378528] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'StoryboardWithName' in bundle NSBundle </Users/Compurex/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1D68DFB6-0841-40C6-A9B1-47FC91377263/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AF3FBE88-822C-4C90-8C8F-937A81C1EAA6/ipad.app> (loaded)'  @Ekta Makadiya

Comment: Please give your storyboard name instead of "StoryboardWithName".

Comment: i dont get it. i guess the name is "main.storyboard" am i correct?

Comment: Yes.
 [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"main"] bundle:NULL];

Comment: - (IBAction)measuring1stscan:(id)sender {
    measuringscan *second = [[measuringscan alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:NO completion:NULL];
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"main"] bundle:NULL];
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard then use following

```
measuringscan *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"StoryboardName"] bundle:nil];
measuringscan *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewcontroller'sIdentifier"];     
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And if you aren't using storyboard instead you are using xib's then use following

```
measuringscan *controller = [[measuringscan alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Points to remember (as said by @rmaddy)

- Class name should be start with capital letter
- Variable name should start with small letter

It is the naming convention that should be followed by a developer.

For more details [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)